# Facebook login on an Android app - Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, xamarin

I'm trying to make an app that will use the Facebook SDK and that you'll be able to login through Facebook. I've just found out [Xamarin.Auth](http://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.auth) after I created the following code :

```
            public int SaveUser(User user)
            {
                int r;
                lock (locker)
                {
                    connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + path + ";Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=sa;Password=***********th");
                    connection.Open();
                    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblUsers (Username, UserEmail, FirstName, LastName, FacebookID) VALUES (@Username, @UserEmail, @FirstName, @LastName,  @FacebookID)";
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserEmail", user.Email);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", user.UserName);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", user.FName);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", user.LName);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FacebookID", user.FacebookID);
                        r = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                    return r;
                 }    
             }
```

I will use this code to insert the data I get from Facebook after the user logs in into the database.
From what I understand Xamarin.Auth does the same only that it passes through some kind of security layers or is it unrelated to it ?
Should I use that component ?

Comment: see this link mab be it is usefull  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/authenticate